# EVP_get_digestbyname : what is this ..?

Tags: c, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I need to use this function

```
EVP_get_digestbyname(OBJ_nid2sn(i));
```

Whenever I call this function it returns NULL only .. how to fix this problem?

My value for i is 65 (RSA-SHA1).

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you call

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

first (ideally when initializing your application) ? This ensures that the algorithms and error messages get properly loaded. After that your call should succeed (cf. the [doc](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms.html) on this subject).